# How do I determine the efficacy of a ranking metric?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference

I have a dataset where I am attempting to perform a classification task. At present only 15% of the data is a positive class. I believe with some feature engineering I've been able to generate a ranking system with the hypothesis, the higher in the ranking system the more likely it is to be in the positive class. To evaluate it I've taken the first 30 and last 30 in the rank and done a ratio of positive to negative class for each and compared the two, expecting the first 30 to have a significantly higher ratio and certainly above 0.15. I was wondering whether anyone had a better/more precise way if there is a genuine signal here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ranking metrics. Examples:

- Precision@K - rank your prediction and calculate out of the top k what was the ratio of true positive.
- Average precision - averaging the precision@K for different Ks.
- DCG & NDCG - rank your data and the give high score for the relevant items and sum them. $\sum_{i=0}{N} \frac {rel_i} {log_2(i)}$  - relevance in your case is a positive example. You can see that the denominator is higher for bigger i, meaning higher gain for the first ranking. NDCG is just a normalized version of it.

For more information you can look at:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank - Evaluation measures section